# how to update render with the new state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jsx

Inserting new values into the array worked, but i want the table to be updated in render

```
this.state = {
materials: [
                {
                    material: {id: 1, label: 'm1'},
                    quantity: 2,
                    unitPrice: 12,
                    total: 0
                },
                {
                    material:  {id: 2, label: 'm2'},
                    quantity: 4,
                    unitPrice: 15,
                    total: 1
                }
            ]
}
```

```
handleOnClick(e){
        this.state.materials.push(this.state.selectedMaterialUnitID, this.state.quantity, this.state.unitPrice, this.state.total);
        console.log(this.state.materials); // this worked fine

    }
```

```
<tbody>
{materials.map((obj) => {return(
    <tr>
        <td >{obj.material.label}</td>
        <td>{obj.quantity}</td>
        <td>{obj.unitPrice}</td>
        <td>{obj.total}</td>
    </tr>
)})}
</tbody>

<Button varient={"light"} onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Add row</Button>
```

expected result is when the table updated and insert the new row

Comment: You need to use `this.setState()`

Comment: see the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set state [setState() tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781)

[official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
handleOnClick = (e) => {

  this.setState({
    materials: [
      ...this.state.materials,
      // add an object 
      { material: this.state.selectedMaterialUnitID,
      quantity: this.state.quantity,
      unitPrice: this.state.unitPrice,
      total: this.state.total
      },
    ]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

React does not know that you updated the state.

When updating states with react, use `this.setState(/* new value */)`.

Your code should look like this:

```
handleOnClick(e) {
  this.setState({
    // just materials. the other keys will not be affected.
    materials: [
      ...this.state.materials,
      this.state.selectedMaterialUnitID,
      this.state.quantity,
      this.state.unitPrice,
      this.state.total,
    ]
  });

  // this will show the old state now, since updating the state is asynchronous.
  console.log(this.state.materials);
}
```

If you want your console.log to reflect the state after the update, you can use the second parameter of setState, like so:

```
handleOnClick(e) {
  this.setState({
    materials: [
      ...this.state.materials,
      this.state.selectedMaterialUnitID,
      this.state.quantity,
      this.state.unitPrice,
      this.state.total,
    ]
  },
  (state) => {
    console.log(state.materials);
  }
  );
}
```

I'm not sure how your `.push` method will work with all those extra parameters, but I hope that you got the point. If you want to add a new object to the array, just add the proper delimiters and keys.

Edit to add: Check this link on why you shouldn't update the state directly: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: are you using `this.setState`? the capitalization is important in this case.

Comment: This is due to `this.handleOnClick` not being bound to this.

In order to bind set `this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this)` in the constructor:

Comment: @vlad-grigoryan -- he had not posted his whole code, so I assumed that he was already binding, since the `console.log(this.state)` was working.

Comment: this was helping! yeah i was using a normal method when console.log() work, i didn't knew that bind is something with handle:p

Comment: congratulations ))

Comment: Hooray! Either use bind, or use "arrow functions", like the other answer from Junius L.

Comment: how was this chosen as an answer, when it doesn't add an object to `state.material`?

Comment: umm sorry Junnis u r right i took the object from ur answer , i tried to choose ur answer too